# How I can exclude an php template from if else

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Wordpress on my website and there is a small section of php code from which I want to exclude a php template.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
.content_right { float: right !important; border-right:0px !important;  border-left: 1px solid #EAE6E6 ;}
.content_right .shadowblock_out { border-right:0px !important;}
.content_left {float: left !important;}
<?php } else { ?>
.content_right {display:none}
.content_right .shadowblock_out {display:none}
.content_left {float: left !important; width: 100%;}
.box {margin: 1px 4px; float: left; width: 24% !important;}
.box .grido {display: block;height: 133px;margin: 2px 3px 5px;overflow: hidden;width: 210px;border: 1px solid #ebebeb;}
#directory {width: 930px !important;}

<?php }?>
```

And I want exclude "single-ad_listing.php" template from ELSE, because I want to shpw the sidebar for this template. How I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a single page is being displayed and further you can give the post type as parameter to be specific.

```
if ( is_singular( "ad_listing" ) ) { // here you need to put the post type 
  // what you want here
} else {
  // what you want elsewhere
}
```